# Displaying a multivalued list box/combo box in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, listbox, multivalue

I have a table containing information about teachers for a university. One of the fields is a multivalued list box containing choices for the types of students that the person teaches (pre doctoral/post doctoral/residents etc). I an trying to display this field on a form, but letting the form wizard create the controls for the form ends up giving copies of the same record with each copy showing a different selection from the students field (i.e. if I select pre and post doctoral, the record selector shows 2 records, both with the exact same information except that one of the student fields says pre doctoral and the other says post doctoral).

I just want to show each option in a list on ONE record. I can't seem to find any kind of property that can do this. I also want to be able to show all possible options when adding a new record. Are there any options/code that will allow for this?

Comment: Just couldn't follow it.  Maybe try putting a few screen shots together, unless someone else can figure out what's being asked?

Answer (score 0):

My answer, which you may not like, is to not use a multi-value listbox (or the Attachments field either). They create hidden tables and relations which you cannot fully control and, as soon as you want to do something useful with them, it becomes problematic. They cause issues with exporting as well.

I would create, and maintain, my own tables (a many-to-many relationship).

Comment: Honestly, I'm not keen on working with them either. It was a table made by someone else that I was trying to get to work with what I was doing. I'm thinking of just giving each option its own checkbox field.